# Same layout looks different in devices which have the same screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 phones: Samsung s6 edge+ and Samsung note 4.
Both have the same screen size (5.7 inch) and the same screen resolution (1440X2560).
Both have xxxhdpi density.

Still the same layout looks different on both devices.

even the top status bar and action bar also looks different on both devices.

Can anyone suggest any solution to have the same UI on every Android device?

[image]

Comment: @Bob Malooga, do you have any solution or suggestion for this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Screen Sizes also depend largely on its PPI resolution and depends on ppi  the android app select the drawables to get the icons or images so you need to check the ppi of devices

Comment: Yes, i know that PPI & Screen to body ration is also matter, but how can we resolve issue due to this, we required pixel perfect screen UI in all the device irrespective of device specification.

Comment: you can create separate layouts or use flat drawables or just check all previews otherwise it is a very difficult task

Comment: Already create 2 layout for each screens to support small & large device. & which works fine. But here issue is 2 device have same screen size & resolution looks different.

Comment: you have option to check all the previews while creating a layout